# java-geotools how to draw continuous wrapped maps

Tags: geotools

geotools support draw continuous wrapped, but Officially no relevant sample code is provided, i don't know how to implement this.
Does anyone know how to do this?

i found WrappingProjectionHandler maybe can do this

```
/**
 * A {@link ProjectionHandler} for projections that do warp in the East/West direction, it will
 * replicate the geometries generating a Google Maps like effect
 *
 * @author Andrea Aime - OpenGeo
 */
public class WrappingProjectionHandler extends ProjectionHandler
```

http://geotoolsnews.blogspot.com/2010/02/geotools-continuous-map-wrapping.html
I hope to achieve the world map effect of the above URL

Comment: So what have you tried so far? What's not working for you? We need to see some code, because as you link to this has been supported since version 2.5